# How did the Gedolim achieve fear of Yom HaDin when the Gemoro says daya letzarah beshatah?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, repentance-teshuvah, rabbis, emotions

The Gemoro says ([Brachot 9b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=9b&format=pdf)) `dayah letzarah beshaatah`. The way I understand this and I think Rashi learns like this as well, is that there is no point worrying about an upcoming Tzarah. If you can do something to stop the Tzarah, then do it. If you cant, then do nothing. [But either way worry and fear is pointless](http://www.needaneitzah.com/q/141).

If this is the case, how to we understand how the Gedolim all trembled in fear of the Yom HaDin? Of course, Teshuva is very important especially if one doesn't want to suffer the consequences of Onesh HaDin. But why were they scared. Whatever will be will be. They should make themselves the best plan of action, but should not be experiencing emotions such as fear and worry; they should be telling themselves `dayah letzarah beshaatah`.

Do not answer my question that the reason why they are scared is because it helps Teshuva. I understand how fear would help the Teshuva process, but they shouldn't be able to get to that fear. Their supreme knowledge and wisdom should stop their fear which they are trying to attain by saying, `dayah letzarah beshaatah`?

Answer (score 6):

If the concept of the Day of Judgement is internalized it will naturally lead a person to fear. Humans have emotions. "Gedolim" are human too. Let's read the Gemara:

> א"ל הקב"ה למשה לך אמור להם לישראל אני הייתי עמכם בשעבוד זה ואני אהיה
>   עמכם בשעבוד מלכיות אמר לפניו רבש"ע דיה לצרה בשעתה א"ל הקב"ה לך אמור
>   להם (שמות ג, יד) אהיה שלחני אליכם
>
> The Holy One, blessed be He, said to Moses: Go and say to Israel: I
>   was with you in this servitude, and I shall be with you in the
>   servitude of the [other] kingdoms. He said to Him: Lord of the
>   Universe, sufficient is the evil in the time thereof! Thereupon the
>   Holy One, blessed be He, said to him: Go and tell them: I AM has sent
>   me unto you.

And Rashi:

> דיה לצרה שיתאוננו בה בשעה שתבא עליהם למה תדאיבם עכשיו בבשורה קשה
>
> Sufficient is the evil that they worry about it when it comes upon
>   them; why cause them sorrow about it now with a harsh tiding?

The Gemara that says *daya tzara besha'ata* means that it is not worth telling someone of a bad thing until it is necessary to. It isn't saying that people should suppress their natural emotions. Actually it is implicit in the Gemara that people do not naturally deflect their fears, because if they did, it wouldn't be necessary to hide the bad news.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21194&pgnum=484

Aimas Yom HaDin comes from the fact that we are standing in front of Hashem.

Comment: He mentions two reasons there, actually. (The other is fear of punishment, which is what the question above questions.) But even the "fear of God" reason mentioned there seems to be not an awe but a fear of what He can do to one, in which case the question above remains intact AFAICT.